# How do I decrease the font size on the default Unity theme?

Tags: unity, fonts

How do I decrease the overall general system font size on the default Unity theme?  I just want fonts to generally be one notch smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Tweak Ubuntu or Unity Tweak tool to fiddle with the settings which include font sizes...

http://www.howtogeek.com/112974/how-to-customize-ubuntu-with-ubuntu-tweak/

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/02/introducing-unity-tweak-tool

Comment: Thanks, the Tweak tool allowed me to set various fonts to my favorite "Serif-9". It looks much better. Thanks!